# Is there a reliable way to detect the app responsible for an Airpush ad?

Tags: applications, ads, airpush

I noticed the other day that my Xoom's notification bar has started receiving [Airpush](http://phandroid.com/2011/04/30/airpush-sends-ads-to-your-notification-pane-and-why-i-think-its-horrible/) ads (which is what it sounds like - push notifications that are really ads). I'm rather philosophically opposed to the idea of push-ads on my device, so I'd like to remove the offending application, but the ad doesn't give you any way to figure this out. Clicking on the notification star only gives you a link to the advertisement page, and nothing more.

I found [Airpush Detector](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.brosmike.airpushdetector&hl=en) in the Market, but it doesn't seem to work on my Xoom, perhaps because of some Android 3.x differences. When I launch the app it says that no Airpush apps were found, but this is obviously not correct. Another option I've seen is systematically freezing apps using Titanium Backup until I find the guilty one, but that would be very time consuming and I'm not even sure if it would work.

I'm also aware of the [permanent opt-out app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.airpush.optout&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5haXJwdXNoLm9wdG91dCJd) in the Market, but I really would rather uninstall the app responsible for the ads (again, due to philosophical beliefs).

Is there any way for me to detect the origin of an Airpush ad?

Answer (score 6):

Two points,

Firstly if you just want to stop getting the AirPush ads, AirPush themselves offer two ways that you can opt your device out of receiving the ads. Either:

- Install the [AirPush Permanent Opt-out](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.airpush.optout) app,
- or visit [their opt-out page](http://www.airpush.com/optout) and follow the instructions to enter your IMEI to be opted out.

Secondly I don't think that AirPush is the only game in town doing this. I uninstalled an app a few months ago when I tracked down that it was the one spamming my notification bar. Its ads didn't look like AirPush's and it didn't show up with an AirPush detector. Didn't track down who was providing the ads framework the app was using, I was just happy to get that rubbish off my device, for an app I only opened once a month or so I didn't need that hassle. It may be that these aren't AirPush ads, but one of their competitors. That app I just tracked down by working out which apps I'd installed/updated recently, then glancing through the Market comments to see which one was full of users screaming to get rid of the notification ads.

Comment: I suppose this is a good point, I didn't really consider the fact that it might not actually be Airpush. It definitely looked like it was, though, based on what I've read about Airpush (same icon, about once per day and such). Do you know the names of any other push ad frameworks offhand? I'm trying to perform a more generic search but I'm mostly just getting pointed back to Airpush.

Comment: @elder I wasn't getting the star icon on each one that you seem to with AirPush. Sorry don't know which framework it was, I was just happy I'd found the culprit and got rid of it, it wasn't an app I used often enough to investigate any further, looking at it they've since removed the push ads.

Answer (score 2):

Install the [Airpush detector app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.brosmike.airpushdetector&hl=en).  This will (in most cases) detect the app responsible.

Comment: As I noted in my question, this app did not find anything on my Xoom, but I was still receiving Airpush ads.

Answer (score 0):

Touch the stars at the top of your phone and slide it down with your finger to view the ad.  Dont open the ad but instead put your finger on it and press and hold it down for 7 seconds and the app thats sending you the add will appear...................delete the app and the stars will go away.  My stars came from downloading the ringtone ( Fart) with my saMsung Galaxy Note 2 .