# How to determine which app is creating a notification

Tags: notifications, notification-icons

I am running Android 2.2 on HTC Legend. I have a LOT of applications installed on it.

Today, after I changed my mobile operator, a notification appeared in the top bar. When I click on it, it says that my connection to Google is wrong and asks for the password.

However, since this is a dialog overlay, I have no mean to know if it is an application that I can trust (like a native one), or some sort of scam.

Any idea on how to identify from which app/service this message comes from?

Comment: It *might* say which app created it in the logcat.

Comment: Could be somewhat related to [Is there a reliable way to detect the app responsible for an Airpush ad?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/is-there-a-reliable-way-to-detect-the-app-responsible-for-an-airpush-ad) If not Airpush then it might be another push-based advertising framework.

Comment: Ok, I have just added a bug to Android :
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26587

Comment: @nomen I don't remember where I read it that it works on Android 2.2 as well but via [tag:adb], the command `adb shell dumpsys notification` would definitely give you good results.

Comment: I too noticed this behaviour in Android 2.2 times. Whenever the active sim is replaced, system prompts for Google account password. Maybe android was too early at that time to display which app gave which notification from the device. I don't think it is malicious because it used to be that way at that time.

Answer (score 4):

This method does not work on Android 2.2.

Tested on **Kitkat Android 4.4.2**

Long press the notification and select `App info`.
It will take you to the settings app and show the details of the app the notification comes from.

on **Lollipop**

A long press shows you the name of the application instead of the notification.