# What is track.dovelane.com and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: malware, ads

Sometimes I get popups for something that claims to be a virus cleaner that redirects me to track.dovelane.com and the again to the play store page for an app called clean master.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard

What is this and what, if anything, is it doing to my phone and how do I get rid of it?

Edit:  The popup was a plain message box that had "track.dovelane.com" in the top and a message saying you might have been infected with a virus in the message. It looks almost exactly like a hostage ware add that you'd see on a desktop.

Comment: CleanMaster is a junk cleaner (used to clean cache and history on your device), and pretty well rated. As it comes even free of charge, I'd wonder if they need such dubious methods to advert it. Do those popups have a pattern, e.g. always happen when you're in a certain app? Maybe you could [edit] your question and include a screenshot?

Comment: If it's an Android notification, then you may want to have a look at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20368/how-to-determine-which-app-is-creating-a-notification

Comment: I've gotten the same thing; it only ever happens in the default internet app, and it pops up every few pages or so. First a pop-up ad over the page I'm on altering me to supposed viruses on my phone; exciting out of the pop-up then redirects the page to "tracking.dovelane.com." If I stay on that page for more than a few seconds, it'll then redirect me to the Google Play store and the above mentioned cleaning app.

Comment: It hasn't happened again for me to get a screenshot but I did update the post with a description of the popup. It always happens in chrome. It started on www.theonion.com and then it started happening on other sites.