# Identifying icon with phone on speaker mode or titled Wi-Fi under a rectangle

Tags: notification-icons, lg-g6

It just appeared today. No idea what it is. When I pull down my notification screen there's nothing new.

I use an LG G6, running Android 8.0.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps somebody else can make a better title for this question.

Comment: Also see: [How to determine which app is creating a notification](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20368/16575). If that helped you figuring for sure, don't forget to let us know here: either [accept](/help/someone-answers) Firelord's answer if it hit the nail, or [answer your own question](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) if not. Thanks, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

While I am not fully convinced, user chuckdawg1999 of [Android Central](https://forums.androidcentral.com/lg-g6/940396-what-icon-appeared-after-recent-update-lg-g6.html?s=ba9a80487bb460042000b089a9b017eb#post6469578) and Community Manager vzw_customer_support [replied](https://community.verizonwireless.com/t5/Android-General/Lg-g6-icons/m-p/1093331/highlight/true#M125027) that the icon is for Wi-Fi Calling or Wi-Fi/HD calling through Verizon.

Comment: Its there even when I disconnect the Wi-Fi

Comment: As I said I am not fully convinced but this is what I could find.