# What is this circle icon for?

Tags: samsung

What for is this circle icon in taskbar?

[image]

Comment: Related question: [How to determine which app is creating a notification](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20368/44325)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the icon of [SHAREit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lenovo.anyshare.gps). Check if it is among your apps.

[image: IMG:]