# How to disable Google news (clickbait) article notifications?

Tags: applications, notifications, services, news-and-weather

Every time I check my phone there is a list of 'news article' summaries in notifications. On the rare occasions I find any of it interesting it almost inevitably turns out to be a low quality fluff piece worthy of the description clickbait..  What is this 'service' and how can I opt out!

I am unaware of any third party news apps on my phone so presume it is some official google thing being pushed on me.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20368/96277

Comment: Thanks for the lead - have already cleared the notifications that accumulated over night but will try the long press info trick the next time one appears.