# How to get rid of ad-ware

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, malware, popup

I've recently installed some games from Google Play Store. Then I uninstalled them all using application manager. The problem is now an advertisement popup appears now and then which stays on top for about 30 seconds and then a close button appears which lets me close it.

How can I get rid of this malware? device is a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 8.0.

Comment: FYI, adverts of this nature are banned on Google Play, so if you find out which game was responsible, you should report it to Google.

Comment: Closely related: [Is this red star icon malware? How to get rid of it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/18232/16575) / [Is there a reliable way to detect the app responsible for an Airpush ad?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14981/16575)

Comment: Without a screen shot or a better description, we're only going to be able to guess at what you might have.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off your mobile data while playing the games. `Settings > More Settings > Mobile Networks > Deselect "Mobile Data"`

But with this, you can't sign in to Google Play Games service (if available in the game).